# String input to date error message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to check whether input from user can be converted to date. If not, there should be an alert that specified value should be date. Please help me to edit my controller (elsif part).

My input text field:

```
= text_field_tag :from, '', as: :string, class: 'datepicker form-control', placeholder: "From", label: false
= text_field_tag :to, '', as: :string, class: 'datepicker form-control', placeholder: "To", label: false
```

Controller:

```
def recalculate
  from, to = params[:from], params[:to]
  if from.empty? || to.empty?
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), alert: "Can't be empty"
  elsif ???
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), alert: "Should be date"
  else
    ...
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), notice: "Was recalculated"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Date.parse`

```
def is_valid_date(value)
  Date.parse(value) rescue false
end

if is_valid_date(from) && is_valid_date(to)
  [..]
end
```

Documentation here [Date#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse)

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method to parse your date values and return either a true or false to keep your code reasonably clean.

```
require 'date'

def recalculate
  from, to = params[:from], params[:to]
  if from.empty? || to.empty?
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), alert: "Can't be empty"
  elsif valid_date?(from) && valid_date(to)
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), alert: "Should be date"
  else
    ...
    redirect_to tarriff_path(@tarriff), notice: "Was recalculated"
  end
end

def valid_date(date)
    Date.parse(date.to_s) rescue nil ? true : false
end
```